# Fixing tab change with caret position in htmleditor in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I need a rich `textArea` control in my javfx application, and found that `HTMLEditor` might be just what I need. However, I'm finding some problems with it.

The GUI looks like this:

[image: EDITOR]

The editor is inside a `Tab` in a `TabPane`, so whenever I press the left arrow key at the beggining of the text inside the editor, the TabPane changes of tab. Same thing happens when I reach the end of the text pressing the right arrow key. I've managed to disable the arrow keys navigation on the TabPane with an event filter:

```
editorTab.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (Arrays.asList(KeyCode.UP, KeyCode.DOWN, KeyCode.LEFT, KeyCode.RIGHT).contains(event.getCode())
                && editorTab.getScene().focusOwnerProperty().get().equals(editorTab)){
            event.consume();
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

So, I was thinking, that maybe if a get the caret position when the key is pressed, I can effectively consume the event, but I can't seem to find a way to get the position of the caret inside the HTML editor.

Is it possible? If not, how can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. When the caret is **in the editor's** area, arrow keys doesn't change the tabs.

Comment: Try holding the arrow keys until the caret reaches the beggining of the text, and keep holding it. Does it change tabs?

Comment: No, it doesn't. BTW, I use JavaFX Scene builder preview...

Comment: Weird, I tried several times and it keeps on happening, I will give it a deeper look.

Comment: Just now I build the project - it works just fine.